# Does this python code employs Depth First Search (DFS) for finding all paths?

Tags: python, graph-theory, depth-first-search

This code is given in [python official essays on graph theory](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/). Here's the code:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if not graph.has_key(start):
            return []
        paths = []
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
        return paths
```

I am not adept at python as I haven't yet had enough of practicing and reading in it. Can you please explain the code by relating this to the child-sibling concept in DFS diagram? Thanks.

Comment: `paths.extend(newpaths)`

Comment: For reference, I would always do `start not in graph` rather than `not graph.has_key(start)` (I'm assuming `graph` is a `dict` or similar).

Comment: Chris, yes `graph` is a `dict`.

Comment: @Harpreet: he's saying use paths.extend rather than paths.append as you're taking a list onto the end - you want something of the style [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] rather than [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]].

Comment: But I am not getting it the form [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]. Rather I get it in the same form you suggested it should be in: ['1','2','3','4','5']

Comment: @Chris: He's iterating through the list and appending each element.

Comment: @Ignacio: arg, I'm getting messed up with the recursive structures... @Harpreet: he's saying replace `for newpath in newpaths: paths.append(newpath)` with `paths.extend(newpaths)`.

Comment: @Harpreet: the `in` thing is the `__contains__` method; for `tuple`s, `list`s and `set`s it checks if the element exists, for `dict`s it checks if the key exists. Various other types may do it different ways.

Comment: This is mediocre python code. Where did you find these essays?

Comment: @Harpreet: that was back in 2000... now you'd probably write the last seven lines as `return [find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path) for node in graph[start] if node not in path]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to seeing that it is a DFS is that the recursion happens before the accumulation of paths.  In other words the recursion will go as deep as it needs to go before putting anything on the "paths" list.  All the deepest siblings are accumulated on "paths" before returning the list.

I believe the code is correct with the "append" rather than "extend", since "paths" is the accumulator of all paths.  Though it could probably be written as

```
paths += find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
```

(edit) ...instead of

```
 newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
 for newpath in newpaths:
     paths.append(newpath)
```

Comment: Thanks mjhm for your answer. Can you tell where to include the line `paths += find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)` you are suggesting?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following modifications and execution script:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    print 'adding %d'%start
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            paths.extend(find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path))
    print 'returning ' + str(paths)
    return paths

G = {1:[2,3,4], 2:[1,4], 3:[1,4], 4:[1,2,3]}
find_all_paths(G, 1, 4)
```

Output:

```
adding 1
adding 2
adding 4
returning [[1, 2, 4]]
adding 3
adding 4
returning [[1, 3, 4]]
adding 4
returning [[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4]]
```

Note how the first path is returned before adding 3, and the second path is returned before adding 4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this algorithm is indeed a DFS. Notice how it recurses right away (go into the child) when looping over the various nodes, as opposed to a Breadth First Search which would basically make a list of viable nodes (e.g. everything on the same level of depth, a.k.a. siblings) and only recursing when those do not match your requirements.