# How to get paths from source node to all other nodes in a graph using DFS?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a graph like below:

```
g = {1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2], 4: [1, 5, 7], 5: [2, 4, 6], 6: [5, 8], 7: [4]}
```

I used a DFS algorithm for exploring the graph `g`:

```
def paths(g,start,path = []):
    path = path + [start]
    for edge in g[start]:
        if edge not in path:
            path = paths(graph, edge, path)
    return path
```

Here I just get a list of nodes that the algorithm explored.  For example, if `start` node is 1 then I get:

```
[1,2,3,5,4,7,6,8]
```

How can I get all paths from the starting node? Let's say the start node is 1, then I want to get:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,5,6,8],[1,4,5,6,8],[1,4,7]]
```

Comment: Try reading:

[Does this python code employs Depth First Search (DFS) for finding all paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230878/does-this-python-code-employs-depth-first-search-dfs-for-finding-all-paths)

And also: 
[trying to find all the path in a graph using DFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741442/trying-to-find-all-the-path-in-a-graph-using-dfs-recursive-in-python)

Comment: should [1,2,5,6] and [1,2,5,6,8] should be found too?

Comment: I do apologies that I did mistake. the paths are: [[1,2,3], [1,2,5,6,8],[1,4,5,6,8],[1,4,7]]. Thanks @Shole

Comment: Thanks @Rafael Cardoso for your suggestion